# I don't understand a question migration

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

Hi everyone. I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934415/is-the-world-ready-for-name-based-https-vhost-service) on stack overflow and it was migrated into server fault. I don't get why. This seems like a question a software engineer would be responsible for answering.

The server admin might ask "Hey Bill, what's your requirements for this service when I install it?"

I would answer, wearing my software engineer hat "It needs to be on an HTTPS only server and will (or not) require its own IP address."

So really, I'm looking for some feedback please where I erred in my reasoning. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like one that could go either way, but I know for sure that if I wanted to know about server setup / hosting, I'd ask on serverfault, so I *suspect* the voters are right, and you'll get better answers there. The network admins tend to have a better handle on these things.

And since you [*accepted an answer*](https://serverfault.com/questions/95978/is-the-world-ready-for-name-based-https-vhost-service/96003#96003), I think that proves it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks more to be about how networking/server then code/api. So serverfault is the place it belongs. Many people on serverfault are programmers so you will get an answer from an engineer point of view if that is what you want.